# Windows Batch Script : Sort folders and process first folder only

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a directory of folders and I am trying write a windows batch script to sort the folders by name and then copy the files in the first folder to a different location.

Directory

- 2020-09-02
- 2020-09-01

Here "2020-09-02" and "2020-09-01" are folders (or sub-folders under the folder 'Directory'). Each folder (2020-09-02 and 2020-09-01) has a set of files inside them.

I need to pick the folder 2020-09-01 (as that is the oldest folder) and copy the files inside the folder 2020-09-01 into a different location, and then delete the folder 2020-09-01.

I do not need to do this in a loop (to process all folders under 'Directory'). I just need to be able to pick the folder with least date and process that folder alone.

I am good with the code to copy the files in a directory to a different location, but having trouble to be able to select the folder with oldest date (without a for loop).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why are you dead set on not using the `FOR` command to get the oldest directory?

Comment: Only other way I can think of doing it is to output the dir listing to a file in alphabetic order and then using the `SET /P` command to read the first line of the file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I only need to process one folder (oldest). Maybe, I can break the for loop after the first iteration, but looking for a better way to do this.

Comment: Yes, the most efficient would be to break the loop after the first folder name read in but if you are sorting newest to oldest, just let the loop do its entire iteration and the oldest will be assigned last.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `/o` switch from `dir` to use the oldest item, the `/ad` switch to only show directories and the `/b` switch to view the directories without volume label and directory info, only shows the files.

```
rem Ensure that 'oldest' variable isn't being used before.

set oldest=

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /od /ad /b') do if not defined oldest set "oldest=%%A"
rem Oldest folder is stored into %oldest%
```

I don't understand why you don't want to use a for loop.
*`for`* statement is probably the most powerful one in batch, take a look at [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) and [Rob van der Woude](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/for.php) `for` explanation and examples.

Comment: I have downvoted your answer because it provides confusing information. The way you have wrote it suggests that the `/O` option in the `DIR` command, means 'oldest', when obviously it does not. The `/O` option means 'order'. With it you can use the `D` sort order for 'oldest first', or `-D` sort order for 'oldest last', when looking at the file object date stamps. In the case above, you're not using the object date stamps, the dates are strings in the directory names which are fortunately formatted in a manner which can be sorted alphabetically, i.e. `DIR /B /A:D /O:N`, or `DIR /B /A:D /O:-N`.

Comment: DIR /B /A:D /O:N worked for me, to order folders by name and then process each folder in a loop.