# Sort and process folders using for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to first sort (by name) the folders in a directory and then process each folder in a loop. I tried to use for loop in below 3 variants of code.

Variant 1 : Below piece of code is working, however I am not sure how to force sort (by name) on the folders

```
cd C:\Process\Daily
for /d %%G in (*) do (
)
```

Variant 2 : Below piece of code is working, however I am not sure how to force sort (by name) on the folders

```
for /d %%G in (C:\Process\Daily\*) do (
)
```

Variant 3: Below piece of code is not working

```
    for /d %%G in (dir /O:N "C:\Process\Daily\*") do (
)
```

When I ran 'dir /O:N C:\Process\Daily*' on command line, I am getting below output

```
  Volume in drive C is Local Disk
  Volume Serial Number is 0AEA-24F6

 Directory of C:\Process\Daily\*

09/16/2020  07:57 AM    <DIR>          .
09/16/2020  07:57 AM    <DIR>          ..
09/16/2020  08:05 AM    <DIR>          09_15_2020
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  22,100,004,864 bytes free
```

In Variant 1 or 2, is there a way I can force/ensure sorting of folders by name,so that I can be sure that the folder with alphabetically lower name is processed first?

What is wrong with the code in Variant 3?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The `FOR /D` command has no sorting options.  If you want to capture the output of the `DIR` command then you need to use a `FOR /F` just like you were shown in your previous question.

Comment: Why not try it using the `/B` option too, you should also include the `D`irectory `/A`ttribute, e.g. `For /F "EOL=? DELIMS=" %%G In ('DIR /B /A:D /O:N "C:\Process\Daily"') DO ...`

Comment: DIR /B /A:D /O:N "C:\Process\Daily"' worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well @Bhanu, you should pay more attention then! I actually provided that exact method in the [comment area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63906572/windows-batch-script-sort-folders-and-process-first-folder-only#comment113012785_63906865), under the only answer of your last question!

Comment: *N. B.:* `cd C:\…` should actually be `cd /D C:\…`…